# How does Recursion Function handle the || operator?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

```
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(current, history) {
      if (current == target)
        {debugger;
        return history;
        }
      else if (current > target){
        debugger;
        return null;
      }
      else{
        debugger;
        return find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
              find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
      }
    }
    debugger;
    return find(1, "1");
  }

  console.log(findSolution(13));
```

During it's working after it reaches find(33, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)") why does this remove +5 from earlier and not *3 it just called?

The working of the code:

```
find(1, "1")
 find(6, "(1 + 5)")
  find(11, "((1 + 5) + 5)")
    find(16, "(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)")
      too big
    find(33, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)") //why does this remove +5 from earlier and not *3 it just called
      too big 
  find(18, "((1 + 5) * 3)")
    too big
find(3, "(1 * 3)")
  find(8, "((1 * 3) + 5)")
    find(13, "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)")
      found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every invocation of `find()` results in a new local `history`. Your recursive calls do not *change* `history`; they make new strings.

Thus in

```
    return find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
          find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

the function is called with the `+ 5` form first, and if that returns `null` then it's called with the `* 3` form. So the `+ 5` is never "removed"; that string is simply discarded.

Also, as to the `||`, if the left-hand expression returns non-null, then the right-hand side is not evaluated at all.

Comment: ok so find(33) is returning null but why is it returning null to previous function call and not to the *3 function it just called?

Comment: @Newbie21if *both* function calls on either side of the `||` return `null`, then that overall expression is `null`. In other words there are two ways that `find()` can return `null`: when `current` is greater than `target`, and when `current + 5` and `current * 3` are *both* greater than `target`.

Comment: Okay so because `find(16)` & `find(33)` are both returning null it in turn makes `find(11)` null so the function rolls back to `find(6)` and the *3 part of `||` is executed leading to `find(18)`.